# MVC 4 java script error unable to get property 'Taskhub'

Tags: signalr

I tried to display signal r messages on my index page. following hub details

```
 public class TasksHub : Hub
{
    public void NewTaskDetails(int taskid,string taskname,string created,string role)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(taskid, taskname, created, role);

    }

}

 my error is : Unhandled exception at line 60, column 9 in http://localhost:45845/
 0x800a138f-JavaScript runtime error:
```

Unable to get property TasksHub of undefined or      null reference

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{

    var THub = $.connection.TasksHub;
    $messages = $("#messages");
    THub.client.send = function (taskid, taskname, created, role) {
        $messages.append("<br /><b>" + taskid + ":</b>" + taskname);
    }

    $.connection.THub.start();
});
```

Comment: Check out the SignalR documentation http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#getproxy

Comment: i go through your link but still same error                                       i got error from connection hub is not detected this is my hub class [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubName("TasksHub")]
    public class TasksHub : Hub
    {
        public void NewTaskDetails(int taskid,string taskname,string created,string role)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(taskid, taskname, created, role);
            
        }

       
    }

Comment: i moved little bit up but now another error  Unable to get property 'client' of undefined or null reference     any suggestions?

Comment: i am trying to test hub is connected or not using this script but it shows error                                                    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { alert("success"); }).fail(function(){alert("failed")});

</script>

Answer (score 0):

use Camel Casing

For Example if Class name MyChatHub

then in you should call
`var chat = $.connection.myChatHub;`

Hope it helps and make sure all script files are loaded  and check in Global.asax file
added

```
  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```